# Using an ASP RadioButton to fire JQuery slidepanel functionality

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a web application.  It is separated into three sections, each with its own asp update panel.

I am using the `$(.Selector).slideToggle('slow')` jQuery method for one of these sections to hide/show the section if the use clicks an HTML link... Another section of the application contains two ASP radio buttons.

I need to trigger the click of the HTML link in order to make one of the radio buttons cause the panel to slide open (or call the same method that is handling the sliding).  However, no matter what I try, I cannot make the radio button open the panel. I have tried registering a script in the code behind, triggering the click using jQuery, and even tried to assign the radio button its on click function using jQuery but still it does not open.  I also tried to remove the update panel around the radio buttons but it is required to make other functionality work (so that there is no flashing and the sliding panel isn't just hidden again). As a matter of fact, I cannot even get an alert to popup when the radio button is selected.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue.  Being a n00b with asp ajax, I didnt realize that I needed to use the ScriptManager static class to register the startup script and not the old ClientScript way.